# How to write a query in an oracle database blob base64 decode in select

Tags: sql, oracle12c

In my DB (Oracle12c), one column (signature) type BLOB and value type base64.
I need to write a type: select id, decodeBase64(signature), msg from message.
I am trying to write a function and use it, but I have failed.

And i I am trying used:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uG5cm.png)
But not correct decode.
I should get such a base64 decryption:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOrDM.png)

Thank.

P.S. - Sorry for my English.

Comment: Please post text rather than images, particularly of code and values. Your query and result don't seem to match as they have different numbers of columns. It would also be helpful to include the original value of `signature` (possibly via `dump()`) , and why you expect that result - perhaps where the value came from? Also, a base-64 encoded value is plain text, so why is that stored as a BLOB?

Answer (score 0):

select m.id, m.message_nom,

**UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_DECODE((m.signature)))**

from message m where id ='5823247';